# I thought instead of... I'd cook something myself

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> Look, I thought instead of eating out today, **I'd** cook something
> myself. What do you say to that?

Would ***I'd=I would*** be the most correct/common option for this sentence construction? Or would ***I will*** or ***I'm going to*** be more likely?

Comment: **I'd** definitely means **I would. I will** would be **I'll**, but that doesn't go with **I thought**.

Comment: Use either Past *I THOUGHT **I'd / I would** eat out*, or Present *I THINK **I'll / I will** eat out* according to your context. But be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first clause is in the past tense ("thought"), the use of "would" (indicating [future-in-the-past](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-in-the-past)) is both correct and common.

As FF says in a comment, if the first clause were in the present tense ("think"), then you could use the future tense ("will"):

> Look, I think instead of eating out today, I'll cook something myself. What do you say to that?